# Problems with X axis position modification in C3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to modify the x-axis position from bottom to top in the graph drawn with C3.  Depending on the circumstances may be used to D3.

[xAxis is top position photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l21kg.png)

I refer to this website. ->[click here. refer site.](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_rotated.html)

Comment: what have you tried so far? add your code

Comment: var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'bar',
        }
    },
    axis: {
        rotated: true
    }
});

Comment: The code of the link above is exactly the same.
I could not think of anything more than that.
I do not know how to do it.
@RealCheeseLord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know of a method in the c3 api that does it, but a bit of d3 tinkering in the onrendered function (along with a bit of padding) will do the job

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'bar',
        }
    },
    axis: {
        rotated: true,
    },
    padding: {
        top: 10,
    },
    onrendered: function () {
        var axis = d3.selectAll(".c3-axis-y");
        axis
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .selectAll(".tick line")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-6)")
        ;
        axis.selectAll(".tick text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,-25)")
        ;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vk6rdty1/

Comment: Your code was a lot of help. That's exactly what I found.